# Shell Script to backup /etc/passwd every 6pm

Tags: linux, bash, shell

how can i create a cronjob that create a backup for /etc/passwd every 6pm.

this should be the output:

```
passwd_<date>.tar.gz
```

i am new in Shell Scripting, trying to figure it out. i read about cron and crontab, but, i can't figure how to create a backup using shell script.. can someone help me.. examples are very appreciated. thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably also want to backup `shadow` along with `passwd`, and possibly also the corresponding `db` files (if you have that configured in your `nsswitch.conf`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `crontab` with option `-e` to directly edit the cronjob:

```
crontab -e
```

The specification of the cronjob is:

```
minute hour day month day-of-week command-line-to-execute
```

The following sets the job to be run everyday at 6:00 PM

```
0 18 * * * tar -czf passwd_`date | tr ' ' '_' | tr ':' '_'`.tar.gz /etc/passwd
```

The command can be an script, in this case is a simple tar command. The name of the file is formed calling the `date` command, converting spaces and colons to underscores. This creates filenames like the following:

```
passwd_Sun_May__3_13_13_00_CDT_2015.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 1):

It *could* be as simple as the `crontab` entry:

```
0 18 * * * gzip </etc/passwd >/etc/passwd_$(date -I).gz
```

run under the privileges of someone able to write to `/etc` (like root).

At 6pm every night, this calls `gzip` using `/etc/passwd` as the input and sends the output to a file of the form:

```
/etc/passwd_YYYY-MM-DD.gz
```

If you have a variant of `date` that doesn't have the `-I` ISO output flag, you can use the slightly more verbose `date +\%Y-\%m-\%d` instead, keeping in mind the `\%` escapes are only needed within the `crontab` file.

There's no *real* reason to create a `tar.gz` file since you're only putting a single file in there any way.

In fact, to be honest, I'd question the need to compress it at all, since it's unlikely to be large. My password file, for example, gets compressed from 2282 bytes to 873 but, even at the uncompressed size, I could quite happily cater for tens of thousands of years worth of backups - about 83M per century.

If you're happy to just *copy* the file, you can use something like:

```
0 18 * * * cp /etc/passwd /etc/passwd_$(date -I)
```

Comment: At least on GNU systems, consider using `date -I` for somewhat more standard output %)

Answer (score 0):

edit crontab with crontab -e 
add this line:
0 5 * * * cp /etc/passwd /etc/passwd_$(date +%a_%d_%Y-%H:%M:%S)

Answer (score 0):

The specific crontab entry you want to use is:

```
0 18 * * *  tar -zcf /etc/passwd_`date "+%Y-%m-%d"`.gz  /etc/passwd
```

This says at 18:00 (6pm) every day run the command to create a compressed tar file (.tar.gz)  containing /etc/passwd.   You didn't say where you wanted to put the tar file, so this example puts it in the /etc directory.  You can simply modify the first /etc/ to be a different directory.   Be sure it is a full path, since cron doesn't have any concept of current directory.

The date part of the filename is generated by  `date +%Y-%m-%d`  which will generate a date in the form of  "2015-06-04"   so the resulting filename would be passwd_2015-06-14.tar.gz    The + sign in the date command says to output a formatted date according to the format characters that follow.   You can use "man strftime" to see a list of all possible codes, so that you can generate a date string to your liking.   All sorts of formats are possible.  For example

```
date "+%e%b%Y"
```

would generate 3Jun2015.  Be sure not to include spaces as they will look like separate arguments to the tar command and not part of the filename.  Use - or _ for separators if desired.   You can practice this by typing this date command at the command line to generate the desired format.

There are multiple ways to edit your crontab file.  The easiest (assuming you know how to use the default 'vi' editor) is by typing

```
 crontab -e
```

The crontab file (blank at first) is opened in the editor and submitted to cron when you exit the editor.